# React - Set component state from external script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React project and I want to add external script to application:

```
<script async src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css"/>
```

and invoke method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {
    easyPack.init({});
    var map = easyPack.mapWidget('easypack-map', function(point){
        console.log(point);
    });
};
</script>

<div id="easypack-map"></div>
```

I did it this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script1 = document.createElement("script");
    script1.src = "https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js";
    script1.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script1);

    const script2 = document.createElement("script");
    script2.type = 'text/javascript';
    script2.async = true;
    script2.innerHTML = "window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {easyPack.init({});var map = easyPack.mapWidget('easypack-map', function (point) {console.log(point);});};";
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
}
```

It is working, but I want to use function return value `point` in my Component (use it as component state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option 1** call from another script: just expose `this.setState`  to an method on window and call that method will update it's state

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.setPoint = (point)=>this.setState('point',point)
}

// open console and run setPoint(xxx) and check the UI change
```

**option 2** call expose the method and call from react as you did, but things can be better

```
<script async src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css"/>
```

you can add these into your template `<head>` tag, html file or html plugin in webpack, add with script may cause repeats

then you just need to

```
componentDidMount() {
    easyPack.init({});
    var map = easyPack.mapWidget('easypack-map', (point)=>{
        console.log(point);
        this.setState('point',point)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution. Set window.point in function and then read window.point in Component

```
script2.innerHTML = "window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {easyPack.init({});var map = easyPack.mapWidget('easypack-map', function (point) {window.point = point);});};";
```

But is it the best solution?